# Django relative import from external app

Tags: django, python-3.x, relative-import, cookiecutter

I'm a 2 Scoops of Django 1.8 reader. Chapter 29 (what about those random utilities) suggests to create a `core` app to store commonly used code. It also suggests that you can use this syntax to import code from it:

e.g.

```py
from core.models import TimeStampedModel
```

How ever it seems that this relative import does not work. I'm using `cookiecutter-django` and I needed to do:

```py
from projectname.apps.core.models import TimeStampedModel
```

I tried adding my `APPS_DIR` to the `path`:

```py
sys.path.insert(str(APPS_DIR))
```

But that resulted in import conflicts given that now there were 2 modules with the same name, `new_app` and `projectname.apps.new_app`.

I just want to avoid explicit imports. Is there a way to include the `Installed Apps` in the python path without creating import conflicts? what are best practices regarding external apps imports?

**edit:** adds project structure

```
.
├── README.rst
├── manage.py
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── common.py
│   │   ├── local.py
│   │   ├── test.py
│   │   ├── production.py
│   │   └── staging.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── projectname
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── apps
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── core
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   └── new_app
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── ...
│   └── templates
│       └── ...
├── requirements
│   ├── base.txt
│   ├── local.txt
│   ├── production.txt
│   └── test.txt
└── tests
    └── ...
```

Comment: Can you show your project/folder structure?

Comment: is there  \_\_init__.py in core app?

Comment: @Gocht, I just added the project structure. @user2707389, yes there is a `__init__.py` in the core app.

Comment: I'm one of the authors of Two Scoops of Django and founder of cookiecutter-django. Your problem stems from what we document at https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django#for-readers-of-two-scoops-of-django-18. Which can be summarized as, "cookiecutter-django is used as test bed for different ideas. Sometimes they work, sometimes they don't". This is one decision I'm not that happy with, and plan to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use relative imports you need to import it this way

from .core.models import TimeStampedModel

This would take the relative path from which the code is being executed, unlike absolute imports which are not supported in Django 1.8

Comment: Well, this would not work because `core` is an external app, it means that is not in the directory where the code is being executed (`new_app`). Regarding absolute imports, they are working correctly in my Django 1.8 setting. @harshatba